# VBA to past certain cell values on different worksheet in predetermined columns

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Gods of VBA,

I would like to request your help on some code i can't seem to get working straight.

Purpose,

When a row has a cell Value "x" on row A in sheet 'Dump', i would like to past certain values in Sheet 'test'.
The values that need to be posted on Sheet 'test', are in column B, D, F and L.

Value from column B, Sheet 'Dump' should go to D4, in sheet 'test'.

Value from column D, Sheet 'Dump' should go to C4, in Sheet 'test'.

Value from column F, Sheet 'Dump' should go to A4, in Sheet 'test'.

Value from column L, Sheet 'Dump' should go to E4, in Sheet 'test'.

Ofcourse i'm trying to make the VBA loop as that when multiple rows on Sheet 'Dump' contains the character 'x', it continues from D/C/A/E4 to the next row.

The code I already have working is posted here:

```
    Sub test()
    Dim i, LastRow
    LastRow = Sheets("Dump").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("test").Range("A2:K200").ClearContents
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Sheets("Dump").Cells(i, "A").Value = "x" Then
    Sheets("Dump").Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "B")).Copy                         
    Destination:=Sheets("test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Have been trying with a lot of different sources of VBA, and some tweaking to it. If i started with a wrong source, or am making some n00b-mistakes, please direct me to what i did wrong. Just trying to learn, while coding.

Comment: Just to clarify (although Tim already gave a good answer) , your problem is a syntax error with the `Destination`?

Comment: My problem at the moment is indeed the destination Command, the fact that i'm not able to rearrange the columns to fit the 'Test' sheet. Going to try Tim's code right now!

Comment: I posted an answer explaining your problem with the `Destination`

Comment: Thank you so much, @arcadeprecinct. Will look in to it when this product is finished. Cheers for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following.

```
Sub test()
Dim i, LastRow
LastRow = Sheets("Dump").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("test").Range("A2:K200").ClearContents
j = 4
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Sheets("Dump").Cells(i, "A").Value = "x" Then
        Sheets("test").Cells(j, 4) = Sheets("Dump").Cells(i, 2).Value
        Sheets("test").Cells(j, 3) = Sheets("Dump").Cells(i, 3).Value
        Sheets("test").Cells(j, 1) = Sheets("Dump").Cells(i, 6).Value
        Sheets("test").Cells(j, 5) = Sheets("Dump").Cells(i, 12).Value
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

You need a separate way of tracking each row in the `test` sheet, hence adding `j = 4` (because you want to start on row 4).

EDIT

I would define your sheets if you call them a a lot.

```
Sub test()
Dim i, LastRow, source as Worksheet, dest as Worksheet
Set source = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dump")
Set dest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("test")
LastRow = source.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
dest.Range("A2:K200").ClearContents
j = 4
For i = 2 To LastRow
    With source
        If .Cells(i, "A").Value = "x" Then
            dest.Cells(j, 4) = .Cells(i, 2).Value
            dest.Cells(j, 3) = .Cells(i, 3).Value
            dest.Cells(j, 1) = .Cells(i, 6).Value
            dest.Cells(j, 5) = .Cells(i, 12).Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a dime! Damn. Thank you so much Tim!

Comment: @Tim Wilkinson try using the `With` statement, it makes code short and beautiful, also reduces errors

Comment: @ShaiRado If it were my code I would, feel free to edit if you wish.

Comment: @TimWilkinson too late, LOL :)

Answer (score 3):

Tim posted the better way to copy values only but here is what is the problem with your code:

The syntax for  copying is

```
sourceRange.Copy Destination:=destinationRange
```

The `:=` specifies an option/paramter to the `.Copy` method. It can be confusing because there are no parentheses around the arguments like you could expect from other languages.

```
someMethod(argument1, argument2)
```

would be

```
someMethod argument1, argument2
```

if there is nothing else in the line (otherwise you need parentheses).

You can specify what argument you use by naming it and using `:=`. This is especially useful for optional arguments or to keep your code readable (you might not remember what each argument is in a few months). Some people keep parameters empty but I think it's obvious why something like

```
someMethod paramName1:=True, paramName4:=False, paramName5:=True
```

is easier to read than

```
someMethod True, , , False, True
```

(I am assuming the parameter names are descriptive like `Destination`).

The parameters of a function need to be in the same row as the function. To concatenate the rows, remove the linebreak (duh) or place an `_` at the end of the line (if it get's to long).

Example with parentheses and linebreaks:

```
Set someRange = rangeToSearch.Find( _
    What:="abc", _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    MatchCase:=True)
```

Example without parenthesis and linebreaks:

```
destinationRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, skipblanks:=True
```

Comment: Hero, hands down. Thanks for the explanation.